# Importing a list of excel files in R by sheet names containing a specific string

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have 36 excel files and need to read only one sheet from each of them into a dataframe.  The sheet names are not all the same but they share a common string (e.g., "Expense Audit", "Jan Expense Audit", "19 Expense Audit").  I would like to write a function to list.files and then use read_excel to pull only the sheets containing the "Expense Audit" string into a single dataframe.

Comment: I think it will be tricky to learn the sheet names before you read in the excel. There are different packages that allow you to read in the excel file and then parse the names of the object. The time consuming part is probably reading in the excel file at the beginning. Once you have the names you can use `grepl` or other function to subset the sheets you want and then continue combining the sheets into one object. Does that help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(purrr)
library(readxl)

#List all the excel files
file_path <- list.files(path = '/path/to/excel/files/', pattern = '\\.xlsx$', full.names = TRUE)

#Read each excel file and combine them in one dataframe
map_df(file_path, ~{
  #get all the names of the sheet
  sheets <- excel_sheets(.x)
  #Select the one which has 'Expense Audit' in them
  sheet_name <- grep('Expense Audit', sheets, value = TRUE)
  #Read the excel with the sheet name
  read_excel(.x, sheet_name)
}) -> data

data
```

Comment: This is exactly the method I was going for.  Thank you!

Comment: @Ronak Shah , I tried the above solution and I am getting an error "Error: `sheet` must have length 1". Can you help me what could have went wrong there?